# asp.net core mvc on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to make a system on asp.net core mvc with mssql or mysql my operating system is Ubuntu 22.04 that's why I need to do that, please guide, I'm getting several errors, some time I'm getting error while adding mssql extension on vs code profile not created try again, some time I'm getting startup.css missing issue etc.

Can anybuddy guide me to make CRUD of asp.net core mvc on Ubuntu 22.04 with vs code mssql or mysql doesn't matter?

Comment: You mentioned multiple issues, but that should split into multiple questions. This site is Q&A for specific questions, not a place to guide you through it all.

Answer (score 0):

Use visual studio is better for c#  ,many codes can be generated automatically.

Here is a simple student name CRUD mvc project.
I create mysql server at :192.168.2.68:3306
[image]
[image]

First create a MVC template then open folder with vscode.
Install Nuget Gallery in vscode extension. Press "ctrl+shift+P" and input "nuget" to start.
Search and install package `"Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore"` and `'pomelo.EntityframeworkCore.Mysql"`
[image]

student.cs

```
namespace WebApplication9
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyDBcontext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


    public class WebApplication9Context : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication9Context (DbContextOptions<WebApplication9Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WebApplication9.Student> Student { get; set; } = default!;
```

Register MySQL database in program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebApplication9Context>(options =>
    options.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=test1;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx", ServerVersion.AutoDetect("server=192.168.2.68;database=test1;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx")));
```

StudentsControllers.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace WebApplication9.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebApplication9Context _context;

        public StudentsController(WebApplication9Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Students
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              return _context.Student != null ? 
                          View(await _context.Student.ToListAsync()) :
                          Problem("Entity set 'WebApplication9Context.Student'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Students/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Student
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Students/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(student);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Student.FindAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Students/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name")] Student student)
        {
            if (id != student.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(student);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!StudentExists(student.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Student
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Students/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Student == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'WebApplication9Context.Student'  is null.");
            }
            var student = await _context.Student.FindAsync(id);
            if (student != null)
            {
                _context.Student.Remove(student);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool StudentExists(int id)
        {
          return (_context.Student?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

All the views should be in "/Views/Students/" folder.
Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication9.Student>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication9.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Delete.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication9.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<h1>Delete</h1>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    
    <form asp-action="Delete">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication9.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Details.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication9.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model?.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

The app Index page
[image]

Comment: It's not working on vs code ubuntu.

Comment: @Mirza Running asp.net core on linux doesn't require much configuration. Maybe you can reference this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnetcore/practice-troubleshoot-linux/2-1-create-configure-aspnet-core-applications